# Trying to use int in getline

Tags: c++, string, int, getline

```
cout << "How many questions are there going to be on this exam?" << endl;
cout << ">>";
getline(cin, totalquestions);
```

This small piece of code comes from a function in a class that I have created and I need `totalquestions` to be an int so that it can run through a for loop and keep asking the total amount of questions that I have asked.

```
question q;
for(int i = 0; i < totalquestions; i++)
{
    q.inputdata();
    questions.push_back(q);
}
```

Where does this piece of code comes to play?  Does anyone have any idea to make this work?

Comment: Please specify what you think is *not* working.

Comment: @ulidtko, actually, for this question, it was pretty easy to see what was not working...

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
cin >> totalquestions;
```

Check the errors too

```
if (!(cin >> totalquestions))
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: @OlayemiIbrahim https://stackoverflow.com/a/4533102/85371 Thanks for [contributing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19527999) anyways!

Answer (score 5):

`getline` reads an entire line as a string.  You'll still have
to convert it into an int:

```
std::string line;
if ( !std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) {
//  Error reading number of questions...
}
std::istringstream tmp( line );
tmp >> totalquestions >> std::ws;
if ( !tmp ) {
//  Error: input not an int...
} else if ( tmp.get() != EOF ) {
//  Error: unexpected garbage at end of line...
}
```

Note that just inputting `std::cin` directly into
`totalquestions` does **not** work; it will leave the trailing
`'\n'` character in the buffer, which will desynchronize all of
the following input.  It's possible to avoid this by adding a
call to `std::cin.ignore`, but this would still miss the error
due to trailing garbage.  If you're doing line oriented input,
stick with `getline`, and use `std::istringstream` for any
necessary conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
int totalquestions;
cout << "How many questions are there going to be on this exam?" << endl;
cout << ">>";
cin >> totalquestions;
```

Getline is meant for grabbing `chars`. It can be done with `getline()`, but `cin` is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

One of the better ways of getting an int from user :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main(){
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss.clear();
    ss.str("");

    std::string input = "";

    int n;

    while (true){
        if (!getline(cin, input))
            return -1;

        ss.str(input);

        if (ss >> n)
            break;

        std::cout << "Invalid number, please try again" << std::endl;

        ss.clear();
        ss.str("");
        input.clear();
}
```

Why is it better than using cin >> n ?

[Actual article explaining why](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/)

As for your question, use the above code to get the int value and then use it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getline`:

```
int totalquestions;
cin >> totalquestions;
```