# C++ trying to have user input values for function calls via getline function

Tags: c++, class, cmath

I am trying to use  class to create a program, that with user input, can perform the operations of the Pythagorean theorum, but i get this error:

Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class PythagoreanTheorum
{

public:

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

    void seta(double A)
    {
        a = A;
    }
    void setb(double B)
    {
        b = B;
    }

    void setc(double C)
    {
        c = C;
    }

    double calcAreea()
    {
        return a * pow(a, 2) + b * pow(b, 2) == c * pow(c, 2);
    }    

};


int main()
{
   //Define one right triangles

        PythagoreanTheorum righttriangle1;

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    cout << "Enter the value for a: " << endl;
    righttriangle1.a = getline(cin, a);

    cout << "Enter the value for b: " << endl;
    righttriangle1.b = getline(cin, b);


    cout << "Enter the value for c: " << endl;
    righttriangle1.c = getline(cin, c);





}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question (out of flags today): https://stackoverflow.com/q/5844309/12448530

Comment: Why not use cin for entering values of a,b and c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use int in getline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844309/trying-to-use-int-in-getline)

Comment: Also, calcAreea() is not proper, this is for pythagoreas theorem right? a^2 + b^2 = c^2?

Answer (score 0):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads strings, not doubles. So you'd have to read with [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and then convert it to `double` (with [`stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)).

You can instead use `>>` operator for inputs, too:

```
cout << "Enter the value for a: " << endl;
std::cin >> righttriangle1.a;

cout << "Enter the value for b: " << endl;
std::cin >> righttriangle1.b;

cout << "Enter the value for c: " << endl;
std::cin >> righttriangle1.c;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write the code, assuming that calcAreea() in your code is meant to show Pythagoreas Theorem being applied.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class PythagoreanTheorum
{
    public:
        void seta(double A)
        {
            a = A;
        }
        void setb(double B)
        {
            b = B;
        }
       void setc(double C)
        {
            c = C;
        }
        double calcTheorem()
        {
            cout<<"Applying Pythagoreas Theorem:"<<pow(a,2)<<"+"<<pow(b,2)<<"="<<pow(c,2);
        }    
    private:
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;

};


int main()
{
    //Define one right triangles
    //Test -> a = 3, b = 4, c = 5

    PythagoreanTheorum righttriangle1;

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    cout << "Enter the value for a: " << endl;
    cin>>a;
    righttriangle1.seta(a);

    cout << "Enter the value for b: " << endl;
    cin>>b;
    righttriangle1.setb(b);

    cout << "Enter the value for c: " << endl;
    cin>>c;
    righttriangle1.setc(c);

    righttriangle1.calcTheorem();
}
```

I removed string header file since it wasn't being used, I also used cin instead of getline since that's way better in this case, also I wanted to not use using namespace std; but since it was in your code I retained it & also renamed calcAreea as calcTheorem since it wasn't calculating area

EDIT: I forgot to mention I declared variables in class in private instead of public