# Infinite cin Loop after reading all data

Tags: c++, loops, cin

SOLVED:
Per the two responses about having a fixed size, i do have a private var for size of array.

Simple solution:  while(i < rhs.size) or a for loop

---

I am getting an infinite loop from this code.  In main I am inputting 1 2 3 4 5

The problem is the even after reading in all 5 int, the system is still waiting for more input.  If I input another int,  it will enter the loop again.

```
template <typename T>
istream& operator>> <>(istream& in, MyArray<T>& rhs)
{
    int i = 0; 
    while(!in.eof()) //I tried: while(in >> rhs.theArray[i]) as well, no go
    {
        in >> rhs.theArray[i];
        i++;
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Don't use eof. Try `while(in >> rhs.theArray[i])` instead.

Comment: When do you expect it to stop reading elements? Do you always want to read exactly 5 elements? Or read until end of line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533063/how-does-does-ifstream-eof-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an int var named size to store a fixed size, once you do that you can just read in for int i = 0; i < size and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Unless of course there is nothing to read ... then you just get stuck blocking for input.  In other words with a fixed-size loop that doesn't have an escape sequence, you *must* input a fixed number of characters.  Anything less will cause the program to hang waiting for your for-loop to complete it's fixed number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

it's safe to say that you should never write `while(!in.eof()) {`.

EOF is set **after** a read attempt, not before. Instead it is better to do something like this:

```
T x;
while(in >> x) {
    rhs.theArray[i] = x;
    ++i;
}
```

What this does is attempt to extract an item from the stream. If after the extraction the stream is still in a "good" state, the body of the loop is executed, if not, the invariant fails and the loop terminates.

In then end, this makes the loop condition "while I could successfully get another item..."

which is a much better way to approach this in general since it also handles conditions besides EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `rhs.Array` is most likely a fixed size (unless you are doing some fancy overloading of `operator[]` to properly expand the underlying memory array) you should only take input for the maximum number of spaces that are in the size of your array, not use a while-loop that could theoretically cause a buffer overflow.

In general, I'd follow these two rules for taking a variable amount of input from the command-line:

1. Define a maximum number of reads depending on the pre-defined space in your array to prevent buffer overflows.
2. Check for an escape character if you want to exit early using something like `istream::peak()` ... keep in mind that `EOF` has to be explicitly send from a command-line using CTRL-D, command-line re-direction from a file, etc.... better choices for escape characters are end-of-line characters like newline, carriage-return (Windows), etc.