# unhandled exception when reading larger file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use this code to read a file and print it out to console:

```
//includes

int main(){
    std::ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Win32w\\gdip.ahk");
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {


            myReadFile >> output;
            std::cout << output;


        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
}
```

but after printing out all the contents of the file I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x51F0742A (msvcp120d.dll) in fourteen.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x002C10AB.
```

When I run a smaller file(script.ahk) with 5 lines it runs OK. The file gdip.ahk has bout 3300 lines.

Comment: Is it your belief that `>>` is able to look at the char* it receives, and know that it points to a block of memory that is 100 characters long, so as not to exceed it?  What did you think it would do if a line exceeded it?  And what inspired you to use a char array instead of a `std::string`?

Comment: And who told you to use `eof`? You should not use `eof`. If anyone tells you to use `eof`, don't listen. You should use `while (myReadFile >> output)`.

Comment: I am fairly new to c++, I just got this code from a page. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

The EOF flag is set after a read tries to read past the end of the file. See here [How does ifstream's eof() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533063/how-does-does-ifstream-eof-work)