# Which header file for eof()

Tags: header, eof

I've tried include and include"studio.h".  Compiler says eof not declared in this scope.

I have
      if(infile.peek()==eof())

I

Comment: Don't you mean infile.eof()?

Comment: Is there any way to peek 2 characters ahead without getting the character.

Comment: Setting infile.peek()==infile.eof() did not work.  How can I check last char for end of file?

Answer (score 2):

You'don't better refer to the following thread: [How does ifstream's eof() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533063/how-does-ifstreams-eof-work)

In C you should include **stdio.h** and use EOF constant.

```
#include "stdio.h"
....
if (getc()==EOF){...}
```

Or use this reference for C++: [cstdio](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
...
 if(infile.peek()==infile.eof())
```