# Deleting a node in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Im trying to delete a node from a doubly linked list with data that's been read in from a file and rewrite it to the file with the non-deleted nodes. But i'm doing this incorrectly.

Either it deletes only a part of the node or it doesn't delete anything (the starting node).

Here's my header

hw07.h

```
#ifndef HW07_H_
#define HW07_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct slist  slist;

struct stud
{
    string term;
    string title;
    string description;
    string tktNum;
    string location;
    string lecDay;
    string instructor;
    string labLoc;
    string labDay;
    string labInstruct;
    string units;
    string preReqs;
    string grade;
};
struct sentry
{
    slist *list;
    sentry *next;
    sentry *prev;
    stud *data;
};
struct slist
{
    int length;
    sentry *first;
    sentry *last;
};

void readFile(slist *&header);
void deleteDataTN(slist *&header);

#endif
```

my main

hw07.cpp

```
#include "hw07.h"

int main()
{
    slist *header = NULL;

    readFile(header);
    deleteDataTN(header);
    return 0;
 }
```

my readFile function

readFile.cpp

```
#include "hw07.h"

void readFile(slist *&header)
{
    ifstream fin;
    sentry *node, *temp;

    fin.open("sbclassdb.txt");
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        if(header == NULL)
        {
            header = new slist;
            header-> length = 0;
            header-> first = NULL;
            header-> last  = NULL;

            node = new sentry;
            header-> first = node;
            header-> last  = node;
            node-> prev = NULL;
            node-> next = NULL;
        }else
        {
            node = new sentry;
            node-> prev = header-> last;
            node-> next = NULL;
            temp = header -> last;
            temp-> next = node;
            header-> last = node;
        }
    node->data = new stud;
    getline(fin, node->data->term);
    getline(fin, node->data->title);
    getline(fin, node->data->description);
    getline(fin, node->data->tktNum);
    getline(fin, node->data->location);
    getline(fin, node->data->lecDay);
    getline(fin, node->data->instructor);
    getline(fin, node->data->labLoc);
    getline(fin, node->data->labDay);
    getline(fin, node->data->labInstruct);
    getline(fin, node->data->units);
    getline(fin, node->data->preReqs);
    getline(fin, node->data->grade);
    header->length++;

    string blankLine;
    if(!getline(fin, blankLine))
    break;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

my deleteData function

deleteDataTN.cpp

```
#include "hw07.h"

void deleteDataTN(slist *&header)
{
    sentry *node, *temp;
    string ticketNum;
    ofstream fout;
    int index;
    bool found;
    found = false;
    index = 0;

    cout << "Ticket Number: ";
    getline(cin, ticketNum);

    node = header->first;
    while(index < header->length && !found)
    {
        if(node->data->tktNum == ticketNum)
        {
            found = true;
            free(node->data);
        }
        else
        {
             ++index;
             temp = node;
             node = temp->next;
         }
        fout.open("sbclassdb.txt");

    node = header->first;
    for(int i=0; i<header->length; ++i)
    {
        fout << node->data->term << endl;
        fout << node->data->title << endl;
        fout << node->data->description << endl;
        fout << node->data->tktNum << endl;
        fout << node->data->location << endl;
        fout << node->data->lecDay << endl;
        fout << node->data->instructor << endl;
        fout << node->data->labLoc << endl;
        fout << node->data->labDay << endl;
        fout << node->data->labInstruct << endl;
        fout << node->data->units << endl;
        fout << node->data->preReqs << endl;
        fout << node->data->grade << endl;

        temp = node;
        node = temp->next;
        fout << "\n";
    }
}
```

my text file used to read in file

sbclassdb.txt

```
Fall 2017
CS1A
Intro to Computer Science 1
11111
SM101
TTH 100PM
John Doe
SM102
TTH 300PM
John Doe
5
NA
A

Spring 2018
CS1B
Intro to Computer Science 2
22222
SM101
TTH 200PM
Jane Doe
SM102
TTH 300PM
Jane Doe
5
CS1A
NA

Spring 2018
CS4A
Into to Java for Computer Science
12345
BGS101
MWF 200PM
Bob Smith
BGS102
Bob Smith
4
CS1B
NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` should be cleaned up with `delete` (not `free` which is for `malloc`)

`struct sentry{stud *data;...}` can be changed to `struct sentry{stud data;...}`. And there is no need for `sentry::list` member:

```
struct sentry
{
    sentry *next;
    sentry *prev;
    stud data;
};
```

There is no gain in declaring `sentry::data` as a pointer. If you simply declare the data as `stud data;` then you don't have to allocate/free with `new`/`delete`. (you still need `new`/`delete` for the nodes)

`void deleteDataTN(slist *&header)` can be declared as `void deleteDataTN(slist &header)`, the you simply call `deleteDataTN(myheader);`

Don't use `while(!fin.eof()){...}`. There are many SO topics on this issue. See for example [how-does-ifstreams-eof-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533063/how-does-ifstreams-eof-work). I wrote a code earlier which I believe was wrong, here is the corrected version:

```
while(fin.good())
{
    sentry *node = new sentry;
    if(header.first == nullptr)
    {
        node->prev = nullptr;
        node->next = nullptr;
        header.first = node;
        header.last = node;
    }
    else
    {
        header.last->next = node;
        node->prev = header.last;
        node->next = nullptr;
        header.last = node;
    }
    ...
}
```

To remove a node, you can add a function to `slist`:

```
struct slist
{
    ...
    void remove(sentry *node);
};

void slist::remove(sentry *node)
{
    if(!node) return;
    if(!first) return;//empty list, do nothing
    if(first->next == nullptr)//deleting the only node
    {
        first = last = nullptr;
    }
    else if(node == last)//deleting the last node
    {
        last = node->prev;
        node->prev->next = nullptr;
    }
    else if(node == first)//deleting the first node
    {
        first = node->next;
        first->prev = nullptr;
    }
    else//deleting a node in the mid
    {
        node->prev->next = node->next;
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
    }
    length--;
    delete node;
}
```

Now you can remove any node

```
node = header.first;
while(node)
{
    if(node->data.tktNum == "xyz")
    {
        header.remove(node);
        break;
    }
    node = node->next;
}
```

Comment: Thank you again Barmak, this extremely helped me. For the unneccessary code (like sentry *data) is because my professor wants us to familiarize  allocating and deallocating memory or i'll lose points.