# Ignoring certain lines in a txt file when parsing

Tags: c++, for-loop, getline, continue

I want to read files from a txt file and compare some lines with regex. 
The first line of the txt file should start with the string #FIRST. 
And if the string should start with a '#' the line should be ignored and it should continue. So counter should have the value 1 which it does and it should go to the second if statement if(counter==1). However it doesn't go to the second if statement.

txt file:

```
#FIRST
#
#haha
```

I expect the output to be good\ngood after the code is run once.

The output is:

```
   good.
```

And it should be

```
          good.
          good.
```

.........

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <regex> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>

  int main() {

    std::ifstream input("test.txt");
    std::regex e("#FIRST");
    std::regex b("haha");
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; !input.eof(); counter++) {
      std::cout << counter << "\n";

      std::string line;
      if (counter == 0) {
        getline(input, line);
        if (std::regex_match(line, e)) {
          std::cout << "good." << std::endl;
          counter++;

        } else
          std::cout << "bad." << std::endl;
        break;
      }

      getline(input, line);
      if (line[0] == '#')
        continue;

      if (counter == 1) {
        getline(input, line);
        if (std::regex_match(line, b)) {
          std::cout << "good." << std::endl;
        } else
          std::cout << "bad." << std::endl;
        break;

      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Hi @senpai - can you post the current output?

Comment: @sanchitarora I have added it to the post at the top

Comment: Count how may `getline` calls are happening. counter = 0 => 2, counter = 1 => 2 but you only have 3 lines... Simple debug (i.e. printing out the line) would help you find this.

Comment: @john I have printed out the lines and I still can't find the problem

Comment: Some restructuring of the code would be advisable considering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533063/how-does-ifstreams-eof-work

Comment: Expanding on @J.R. 's comment, [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `break` statement in the first `if` clause. After getting the first line of the input the program encounters the `break` statement and breaks out of the loop immediately. No further statements are executed within the for loop which I believe is the behavior you are seeing. You will have to restructure the program to be something like:

```
for loop {
  getline()
  if (counter == <>) {
    // no break
  } else if (line[0] == '#') {
    continue;
  } else {
    // whatever else you want to get done
  }
}
```

Comment: I used your approach and I still face the same problem