# Get more values with istringstream

Tags: c++

When I input **[1,0,0,1,0]** I get output with **1 0 0 1 0 0**, I don't know why there is an extra zero and why the *while* loop doesn't terminate after *]*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::istringstream is;
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    is.str(str);
    char ch;
    is >> ch;
    while (!is.eof())
    {
        int num;
        is >> num >> ch;
        numbers.push_back(num);
    }
    for (auto num : numbers)
        std::cout << num << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the while loop part will get expected behavior:

```cpp
  int num;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  while (is >> num >> ch) {                                                                                                                                                                                            
    numbers.push_back(num);
  }
```

The `eof` check is misused here, so the last character read failed and get a default number 0. Read this answer for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4533102/1292791